# Any example on how to implement the new VerificationController and the KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY constant?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I've been looking at implementing the new VerificationController to verify in-App-Purchases:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html

And I wonder if there is some example anywhere en how to validate a transaction, since it seems that the `- (BOOL)verifyPurchase:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction;` is not enough and it has to be implemented internally to verify the purchase when the data form the server is received.

Another question is if anyone has a clue on what the KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY is and how to fill it, is it just the product id of the purchase?

Comment: can u share, which functions u r using for   void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size), i'm using my own decoders but they are all time return empty strings.

Comment: Well, I haven't started to use the VerificationController since I don't know what the KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY is yet. Any clue? I took a look at the functions `base64_decode` and `base64_encode` inside the VerificationController.m and they are empty.

Comment: The Base64 functions have to be filled, I think that a good option would be to check: Base64Transcoder from Jonathan Wight, I think this will do (just google for them)...

Comment: me too, bcs i'm also don't know where i can get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the file "VerificationController.m", check this function:

```
- (void)saveTransactionId:(NSString *)transactionId
```

we can see, KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY is a key to be wrote to NSUserDefaults. So we don't need to touch it.

login **iTunes Connect** > **Manage Your Apps** > (click your app) > **Manage In-App Purchases** > click the link **View or generate a shared secret** (at bottom-left of the page)
it'll show us:

> A shared secret is a unique code that you should use when you make the
>   call to our servers for your In-App Purchase receipts.

Just click Generate.

Comment: Apparently, the shared secret is only available in iTunes Connect for [auto-renewable subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW9). I'm not sure if that means that this value in VerificationController.m is unused in other cases, or what.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr Nope, not just for subscriptions. I see a secret for my app and I have only non-consumables. I have no subscriptions, neither now nor in the past.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a complete implementation over here: https://github.com/evands/iap_validation

Comment: I love you!  Thanks for that link!!!!!!! I was banging my wall in the head and cursing Apple for a week.

Comment: Using the above code, is it still necessary to do receipt validation on your own server?  If so, how does that plug into the above code?  My App only runs on 5.1 and above.

Answer (score 3):

## RayWenderlich.com Tutorial

This article, [In-App Purchases in iOS 6 Tutorial: Consumables and Receipt Validation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation) on the *RayWenderlich.com* site, offers a download of Apple's code but fleshed-out (including Base64 methods) and tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the validation on a transaction when it changes to one of the completion states:

```
SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased 
SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored
```

call the function:

```
[[VerificationController sharedInstance] verifyPurchase:transaction];
```

As you say it is not enough to just look at the return value.  The function is asynchronous.  You need to add some code to VerificationController.m where it says:

```
#warning Validation succeeded. Unlock content here.
```

There are also a few other lines with #warning in VerificationController.m where you need to deal with errors.

As for base64 another library you might want to look at using is:

http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php

When it comes to

```
 KNOWN_TRANSACTIONS_KEY
```

and

```
ITC_CONTENT_PROVIDER_SHARED_SECRET
```

I too would like to know what they are for and why and when they are needed.

Comment: ITC_CONTENT_PROVIDER_SHARED_SECRET u can see in u Purchase InApps area in itunesconnect.